# Find the period of $\cos x -\sin x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Let $f$ be the function of domain $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
>
> $$f(x) = \cos x - \sin x$$
>
> Show that $f$ had period of $2\pi$.

How do you find the period of a function that has several trigonometric functions like this one?

I tried converting them all to sine:

$$f(x) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}-\sin x$$

But what do I do next?

Comment: Half of the time, $\cos x\ne\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite:
$$f(x) = \color{blue}{\cos x} - \sin x = \color{blue}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}- \sin x$$
and then use:
$$\sin a - \sin b = 2\cos\left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right)\sin\left( \frac{a-b}{2} \right)$$
to find that $f(x)$ can also be written as:
$$f(x) = \sqrt{2}\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{4}-x \right)$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. By the way, I read that since the periodicity of $\cos x$ is $2\pi$ and the periodicity of $\sin x$ is also $2pi$ then the "compound periodicity" is $2\pi$. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: @Mark Read. I'm not sure where you got that but there is no simple, general "sum rule". Consider for example $\sin^2 x$ and $\cos^2 x$, both have period $\pi$ but their sum...

Comment: I got it from here https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%3Dcos%20%5Cleft(x%5Cright)-%5Csin%5Cleft(x%5Cright) (where is says periodicity click "Show Steps")

Comment: I can't open it now (on my phone), will look at it later if I remember.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $\cos x - \sin x$ to $-\sqrt{2}\sin(x-\pi/4)$ and it is obvious that period is $2\pi$

Another way : $T> 0 $ then

$\cos(x+T) - \sin(x+T) = \cos x - \sin x \to \sin x - \sin(x+T) = \cos x -\cos(x+T) \to                   \  \ \ \ 2\sin(\frac{-T}{2})\cos(\frac{2x+T}{2}) = -2\sin(\frac{2x+T}{2})\sin(\frac{-T}{2}) \to \sin(\frac{-T}{2})(\cos(\frac{2x+T}{2}) + \sin(\frac{2x+T}{2})) = 0 $
And then you can find $T$ .

Comment: @JohnHughes Ok , $\cos 0 - \sin 0 = 1 - 0 = 1$ and $-\sqrt{2}\sin(x-\pi/4) = -\sqrt{2}\sin(-\pi/4) = \sqrt{2}\sin(\pi/4) = \sqrt{2} \ . \ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = 1$

Comment: The $\sqrt{2}$ was missing when I started typing my comment.

Comment: So it is okay now ?

Comment: Looks that way; I'd be inclined to absorb the "-" sign into the "sin", but that'd  just be @StackTD's answer. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes Okay , Thank you :)