# Find the signal and zeros of $\cos x - \sin x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Let $f$ be a function of domain $\mathbb{R}$ defined by:
>
> $$f(x) = \cos x - \sin x$$
>
> Find the signal and zeros of the function.

First I tried to find the zeros of $f(x)$:

$$0 = \cos x - \sin x \Leftrightarrow \\
0 = \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}-\sin x \Leftrightarrow \\
\sin x = \sqrt{1-\sin^2x} \Leftrightarrow \\
\sin^2x=1-\sin^2x\Leftrightarrow \\
2\sin^2x=1 \Leftrightarrow \\
\sin x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Leftrightarrow \\
x = \frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi \lor \pi - \frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi \Leftrightarrow \\
x = \frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi \lor \frac{3\pi}{4}+2k\pi $$

But then when I check the value of $f(x)$ for the answers above, $\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi$ gives me a zero while $\frac{3\pi}{4}+2k\pi$ gives me a minimum. Why is that?

As for the signal, $\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi$ gives me the zero on the left side when the function becomes negative.

My book states the solution is

> Zeros:
>
> $x = \frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi, k\in \mathbb{R}$
>
> $f$ is negative in the intervals
>
> $$]\frac{\pi}{4}+k2\pi,\frac{5\pi}{4}+k2\pi[,k\in\mathbb{Z};$$
>
> $f$ is positive in the intervals
>
> $$]-\frac{3\pi}{4}+k2\pi,\frac{\pi}{4}+k2\pi[,k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

How do I solve this?

Comment: If $\cos(x)=0$ then $\sin(x)=\pm 1$. So solve:

$$\tan(x)=1$$

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267274/find-the-period-of-cos-x-sin-x

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)=\cos x−\sin x = \sqrt {2} \cos (x+\frac \pi 4)$

more generally

$a\cos x+b\sin x = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \cos (x - \tan^{-1}\frac ba)$

Comment: OR $$=\sqrt2\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4-x\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

There is a trigonometric identity $\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y)$. Put $y = 3\pi/4$ to show $f(x) = \sqrt2\sin(x+3\pi/4)$. This quickly gives the answer you want.

You asked about some spurious extra solutions. I think these come from using $\cos(x) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$. This is true only if the square root has the right sign.